# No more volume OSD after 14.10 -> 15.04 upgrade

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, notification, notify-osd, 15.04

In 14.10 when I pressed a volume key on my keyboard, the volume value would show in a popup in the top right corner of the screen.

The volume keys still work (I can hear the "pop" sound) but the notification popup does not show anymore since 15.04. Is it something normal for 15.04? How can I enable it back?

I still have notifications but one strange thing I noticed is that when the notification popup appears, for example when a new mail is received in Thunderbird, or by manually sending a notification with "notify-send" from a terminal, the look&feel of the popup is not the same at all than with 14.10. The background is now light gray instead of being dark brown/gray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason I had another notification daemon running, so I uninstalled it before reinstalling notify-osd:

```
sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd
sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd
```

then reboot.

Comment: I didn't have to do the "remove" step for xfce4-notifyd. I just reinstalled "notify-osd" and that worked fine.

Comment: Would you accept your own answer as that's what works for you. Please make a look on https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Same here, remove not necessary, but the reinstall did the trick. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 16.04, I had to uninstall this notification daemon to get the volume OSD to work:

```
sudo apt purge notification-daemon
```

Then log out and in again.